# Finding different numbers with same digits from an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of 6 digit numbers in which I need to find numbers with same digits but with different order. How can I do this in vba?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Answer (score 2):

I feel a good way to do this would be to take your 6 digit number, create an array containing those 6 digits, sort them, then give you the new number (returned as a string in this example) then compare the two to make sure they are equal.

```
Public Function SortNumber(intIn As Long)
    Dim intArr(1 To 6) As Integer, strResult As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 6
        intArr(i) = Mid(CStr(intIn), i, 1)
    Next i

    BubbleSort intArr

    For i = 1 To 6
        strResult = strResult + CStr(intArr(i))
    Next i

    SortNumber = strResult
End Function

Function BubbleSort(TempArray As Variant)
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NoExchanges As Integer

    Do
        NoExchanges = True
        For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray) - 1
            If TempArray(i) > TempArray(i + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                Temp = TempArray(i)
                TempArray(i) = TempArray(i + 1)
                TempArray(i + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)
End Function
```

Comment: I absolutely tested the code, intArr is just holding the 6 different digits that make up the total number, so integer is fine here. (1,3,5,7,8,9 if the number was 135789 for example).  Although I do agree that it shouldn't be the full code, I had something very similar to this already written up.

Comment: Yes, and using this code, you can compare the two numbers (once sorted) to make sure they match.  654321 and 561234 would both return the same number (123456) and from there you could make sure they are equal.

Comment: Thanks :) after your comments I realized it made much more sense to right it as a function to use throughout the array.

Comment: ++ Works perfectly :)